# how to deserialize json in scala and java

Tags: java, json, scala, apache-spark

I am new to scala. I need to connect to my database and select a column called "queue_message" from table "queue". This column consist of a json schema:

```
{"LOG_ID":"2442204","CUSTOMER_CODE":"79D3QL","CFILE_WEIGHT":"1","PROVIDER_ID":"","FILETYPE_DIRECTORYFROM":"\\FromCustomer","FILE_CHARSET":"","CFILE_FORMAT":"CSV","FILE_NAME":"1475_18032018T164840_1.csv","FILETYPE_LABEL":"Order","FILE_ID":1475,"FILEFORMAT_CODE":"","CUSTOMER_ID":1016,"FILE_MASK":"wt_cde_*-*_*.csv"}
```

I need to deserialize this column in scala (or in java as a second option), and then  to serialize another structure to json format.

this is my code in scala:

```
package com.orienit.spark.training.sparkexamples

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import java.sql.DriverManager
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc
import org.apache.spark.rdd.JdbcRDD
import java.sql.ResultSet




object WordCount {
  def main(args: Array[String]){

val conf = new SparkConf()
 .setAppName("my first scala App")
 .setMaster("local")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val url =  "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;user=xsxx;password=xxx;databaseName=xxx"
val df = sqlContext


.read
   .format("jdbc")
   .option("url",url)
   .option("dbtable","(select top 1 queue_message from mq..queue where queuename_id = 4 order by queue_id desc) as sq")
   .load()

   df.show()
    println( df.collectAsList())
     }
}
```

these are the dependencies I used in the maven pom.xml of my scala project:

```
<dependencies>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

and this is my code in java:

```
package com.orienit.spark.training.javaJdbcConnectivity;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;

public class WordCount {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("My app");
    JavaSparkContext sc  = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

    SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);

    Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<String, String>();




   options.put("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;user=xsxx;password=xxx;databaseName=xxx");
options.put("dbtable", "(select top 1 queue_message from mq..queue where queuename_id = 4 order by queue_id desc) as sq");

Dataset<Row> df = sqlContext.read().format("jdbc"). options(options).load();
df.show();
System.out.println(df.collectAsList());
System.out.println(df.toJSON());


    }

}
```

these are the dependensies of my java project

```
    <dependencies>
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

can anyone help me please to serialize to json format and deserialise from a json  format, or give me any relevant documents about this subject. I did not find in the official spark documentation something helpful for this king of operations.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I have not worked on scala but for Java you can use Jackson for deserialization . Shared a link for your reference https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the from_json function in spark.

Assuming the schema of the json is "schema" then you can simply do:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.from_json
df.withColumn("deserialized", from_json($"queue_message", schema)
```

Comment: thanks Assaf; Is there a way to detect or construct the schema automatically from the result of the query. This is an example of queue_message content: {"LOG_ID":"3102116","PFILE_MATCHINGFIELD":"Delivery_Reference","PROVIDER_ID":42,"TRACE":{"TSTATUS_CODE":"MLRCFM","TRACE_HOUR":"03:70","TRACE_DATE":"180530"},"MATCHINGFIELD":"114146490000000058905001001","CUSTOMER_ID":1051}. Can you give me please an example of declaration of the variable schema for this case. I tried val schemaString = "LOG_ID;PFILE_MATCHINGFIELD;Delivery_Reference;PROVIDER_ID;TRACE;MATCHINGFIELD;CUSTOMER_ID" but  does'nt work

Comment: and then val fields = schemaString.split(";")
  .map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, nullable = true))
val schema = StructType(fields) because in Trace I have TStatus_Code,Trace_Date and Trace_Hour

Comment: There are two issues here: The first is that the json configuration might not be @user3569267 constant across all elements (e.g. what happens if there is a missing value because it is null in one of the rows). The second is that analyzing the field is just like doing from the from_json yourself. i.e. you would create a udf which would return a Row containing the data. This would be more cumbersome and less performance though.